# use of order by function in group by query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT com_jobcard.job_card_num, sum( worked_qty ),employee.emp_name
FROM timer_completed
INNER JOIN process ON process.id = timer_completed.process_id
INNER JOIN com_jobcard ON com_jobcard.id = timer_completed.job_card_id
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = timer_completed.employee_id
AND process.id = '611'
AND timer_completed.group_id = '60'
AND timer_completed.report_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
GROUP BY com_jobcard.job_card_num
UNION 
SELECT job_card_num , die_qty,id FROM com_jobcard
```

In the First query I would like to order the result set in `Orderby timer_completed.report_date DESC` , but I have used `Groupby` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
GROUP BY timer_completed.report_date, com_jobcard.job_card_num
ORDER BY timer_completed.report_date DESC
```